# Relação entre documentos - MongoDB

Tags: banco-de-dados, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Possuo o seguinte modelo:

- Um schema chamado suspeitos, o qual possui informações de pessoas suspeitas.
- E outros 3 chamados alertas, ações criminosas e eventos de risco.

Estes 3 outros schemas, devem possuir os dados dos suspeitos, por exemplo, o mesmo suspeito pode aparecer nos 3 casos.
Ou seja, se fosse um BD relacional seria uma relação de `n:n` (1 ou mais suspeitos para 1 ou mais casos).

Utilizando BD não relacional (MongoDB), qual a melhor prática para criar esses schemas? Vou demonstrar como eu fiz:

**Suspeitos Schema**:

Criei um arquivo diferente para deixar separado por diretórios.

```
const restful = require('node-restful')
const mongoose = restful.mongoose

const suspeitosSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nome: { type: String, required: true }
})

module.exports = restful.model('suspeitos', suspeitosSchema)
```

**Alertas Schema**:

```
const restful = require('node-restful')
const mongoose = restful.mongoose
const suspeitos = require('./suspeitos') //posso acessar um schema que está em outro arquivo desta forma?

const alertasSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  suspeitos: [suspeitosSchema]  //<-- Isso esta certo?  
})

module.exports = restful.model('alertas', alertasSchema)
```

Ainda existem os outros dois schemas, o eventos de risco e ações criminosas, mas estes são parecidos com o alertas.

O que eu fiz para relacionar os suspeitos com alertas está correto?

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade o correto mesmo seria usar o `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`, porque ai na hora de de um `find({})` tu pode usar o `populate` para buscar as informações do outro esquema. Ficaria assim.

```
const restful = require('node-restful')
const mongoose = restful.mongoose

const alertasSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    suspeitos: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'suspeitos'
    }]  
})

module.exports = restful.model('alertas', alertasSchema)
```